# Mysqli multi_query Search of 2 Tables Not showing Results

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I'm up to my neck trying to figure out why my query isn't working. This is what my search.php page results in. I am able to _GET the search term perfectly but can't display the results.

Not sure if the issue is the fetch_array_assoc or what! Here's my code. Any help with this would be appreciated. Not 100% sure if my syntax is correct.

```
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$button = $_GET ['submit'];
$search = $_GET ['query'];

if (strlen($search) <= 1) {
    echo "Search term too short";
}
else {
    echo "You searched for <b>$search</b> <hr size='1'></br>";
    $con = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "pass", "db");

    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $search_exploded = explode(" ", $search);
    foreach ($search_exploded as $search_each) {
        $x++;
        if ($x == 1) {
            $query = "Keyword_ID LIKE '%$search_each%' or Keyword_Name LIKE '%$search_each%' ";
        }
        else {
            $query .= "OR Keyword_ID LIKE '%$search_each%' or Keyword_Name LIKE '%$search_each%' ";
        }
    }
    $construct = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM profileTable WHERE $query");
    $construct = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM addKeywordTable (Keyword_Name) WHERE $query");
    $constructs = mysqli_multi_query($construct);

    if (mysqli_multi_query($construct)) {
        $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
        if ($numrows > 0) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($constructs)) {
                $key = $row['Keyword_Name'];
                $keyID = $row['keyID'];
                $fname = $row['FirName'];
                $lname = $row['LaName'];
                $mname = $row['MName'];
                $suffix = $row['Suffix'];
                $title = $row['Title'];
                $dept = $row['Dept'];
                $phone1 = $row['PH1'];
                $phone2 = $row['PH2'];
                $email = $row['Email'];
                $photo = $row['Photo'];
                $bio = $row['BioLK'];
                $tags = $row['Tags'];

                echo '<h2>$fname $lname</h2>';
                echo $key;
                echo $title;
                echo $dept;
            }
        }
        else {
            echo "Results found: \"<b>$x</b>\"";
        }
    }
}
mysqli_close();
?>
```

I am trying to search two different tables. addKeywordTable and profileTable. Profile table has all of the profile info for a user. The addKeywordTable stores the keywords/tag names 'Keyword_Name'.

I attempted to create a mysqli_multi_query but its not working at all.

Comment: I don't think you're generating the SQL you think you're generating.  Try writing out the logic in pseudocode, and writing the actual SQL you think you're submitting.

Comment: Also, your DB Schema, and the actual output that you're getting.

Comment: Thanks @FrankieTheKneeMan but that's obvious. Any help with this would be great. Thanks...

Comment: Help us help you - I asked you for four pieces of information so I could better diagnose the problem at hand, not just for fun.

Comment: I dont see where you asked me for four pieces of information. Why so frustrated?

Comment: I had asked you for (1)The logic in pseudocode (2) The SQL you think you're submitting (3) Your DB Schema, and (4) the output you were getting.  And I'm wasn't frustrated - I was simply pointing out that you hadn't provided enough information for me to help you.  Glad someone else was able to help.

Comment: Those are questions? You made comments but never asked a question so i never responded. Went on to the comment/ideas Moskito provided which was logical and made sense. Luckily he didnt get frustrated... but instead provided help. Thanks @Moskito

Comment: Miz, I'm trying to help you get help here in the future.  I've been around a while, and I feel you need to know this pedantic "You never asked a question" attitude is going to hurt you - there's a reason so many of your questions haven't been answered.  When I say "Try writing", it's natural to assume that it's intended that you modify the question with the information I suggest you write.  I'm glad @moskito-x was able to help, really I am, but when people make comments on your question, know that it's not coming from a place of criticism.  We're here to help.

Comment: Yikes... tone it down a notch. You said you asked me 4 questions but you didnt. @moskito kindly replied with help and his suggestions solved my problem. Whatever is natural to you isnt to others perhaps. I have no attitude, only came for help and i kindly received it from others. Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assuming:

$con is set by

```
$con = mysqli_connect("host", "user", "password", "db");
```

mysqli_multi_query : you must all sql commands, except the last, terminate with `;`
and concenat `$construct` with `.=` . Otherwise you overwrite your `$construct`.

```
 $construct  = "SELECT * FROM profileTable WHERE $query ;");
 $construct .= "SELECT * FROM addKeywordTable (Keyword_Name) WHERE $query");
```

don't set $construct with

```
$construct = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM profileTable WHERE $query");
```

your `$construct` will only become TRUE or FALSE .
with a variable wich contents `TRUE or FALSE`you can not call

```
$constructs = mysqli_multi_query($con,TRUE);
```

And you call it wrong

```
$constructs = mysqli_multi_query($construct);
```

correct

```
$constructs = mysqli_multi_query($con,$construct);
```

You call `mysqli_multi_query($construct)` twice

```
$constructs = mysqli_multi_query($construct);
if (mysqli_multi_query($construct)) { ...
```

the first call is not necessary.

call it only with

```
if (mysqli_multi_query($con,$construct)) { ...
```

complete wrong is

```
if (mysqli_multi_query($construct)) {
    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
      if ($numrows > 0) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($constructs)) {
```

`$query` is at the moment a simple 'string'

```
$query = "Keyword_ID LIKE '%$search_each%' or Keyword_Name LIKE '%$search_each%' ";
```

Also wrong

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($constructs)) {
```

`To retrieve the resultset from the first query you can use mysqli_use_result() or mysqli_store_result(). All subsequent query results can be processed using mysqli_more_results() and mysqli_next_result().`

Call it like this instead

```
if (mysqli_multi_query($con,$construct)) {
   if ($result = mysqli_store_result($con)) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
            printf("%s\n", $row[0]);
        }
        mysqli_free_result($result);
```

---

Set `$x` before you do `$x++` .

```
$x = 0;
```

You can't be sure that `$x` is always automatically set to `0` .